# how to make Clock Angle Problem with python?

Tags: function, dictionary, if-statement, printing, return

Clock Angle Problem: Given time in hh:mm format in 24-hour notation, calculate the shorter angle between the hour and minute hand in an analog clock.

Input:  5:30
Output: 15°
Input:  21:00
Output: 90°
Input:  12:00
Output: 0°

Answer (score 0):

```
def clock_angle(time):
  # Extract the hours and minutes from the time
  hours, minutes = map(int, time.split(':'))
  
  # Calculate the angles of the hour and minute hands
  hour_angle = 30 * hours + 0.5 * minutes
  minute_angle = 6 * minutes
  
  # Calculate the shorter angle between the hour and minute hands
  angle = abs(hour_angle - minute_angle)
  if angle > 180:
    angle = 360 - angle
  return angle

# Test the function
print(clock_angle("12:00"))  # should print 0
print(clock_angle("3:00"))   # should print 90
print(clock_angle("6:00"))   # should print 180
print(clock_angle("9:00"))   # should print 90
print(clock_angle("12:30"))  # should print 165
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).